# Problem installing Microsoft iSCSI initiator on Windows 2003

Tags: iscsi, windows-server-2003-r2

Anyone got any idea what this is about:

[image]

"Windows iSCSI200 has detected one or more protected files on your computer have been modified".

I'm guessing that a service pack or Windows update has modified one of these protected files as it's a new clean build of Windows 2003 R2 x64 with SP2.

What's worrying is that neither response seems very safe. Update the files and problems with customisation. Say "No" and computer might stop responding...

What's unusual is that this dialog appears on running the iSCSI initiator setup but before actually accepting the installation.